# About React Context: Property 'children' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'ConsumerProps<T>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am new to React Context,the code below can work but there is always a type error.

```
<AppContext.Consumer>
     {({ value }: { value: string }) => <div>{value}</div>}
</AppContext.Consumer>
```

> Property 'children' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'ConsumerProps<...>'.ts(2741)
> index.d.ts(342, 9): 'children' is declared here.

```
interface ConsumerProps<T> {
        children: (value: T) => ReactNode;
    }
```

and i think `{({ value }: { value: string }) => <div>{value}</div>}` should be detected as children just the ConsumerProps want, but it doesn't. And if i  write the code like

```
        <AppContext.Consumer
          children={() => {
            return <View />
          }}
        />
```

There has a eslint constraint

> Do not pass children as props. Instead, nest children between the opening and closing tags.
> eslintreact/no-children-prop

How could i do to solve this without change the eslint constraint.

Comment: If you don´t type the `{value}` part do you still get the error? ie. `{({ value })) => <div>{value}</div>}`. Also what React version you are using? Your code seems like it should not give TS compiler errors.

Comment: If I don't type value, there is an error `Binding element 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type.`  React version is 16.10.0.